# Style custom component with material ui styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [NumberFormat](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) package but I would like to style it as if I was using a TextField from [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/).

My component is as follow:

```
<NumberFormat label={strings.minDays} style={{marginRight:'20px'}}/>
```

I already tried several things without any success:

- Add a `className` attribute to 'FormControl';
- Add a `classes` attribute to 'FormControl';
- Prefixing it with `(withStyles)`

But I'm kind of lost and not sure how to achieve my goal.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import YourCustomInput from 'custom';
 <NumberFormat 
  customInput={<YourCustomINput style={{}} className="CustomClassName"/>} 
  format="#### #### #### ####"/>
```